# Can I use boost operators to generate comparision functions for 2 objects(with different types) of class?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I would like to use [boost operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) to generate comparision functions in such way:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo : boost::less_than_comparable<Foo<T>, Foo<T2> > {
    private:
        int bar;
    public:
        template <typename T2>
        friend bool operator<(Foo<T> const& f1, Foo<T2> const& f2) {
            if (typeid(T) == typeid(T2)) {
                return f1.bar < f2.bar;
            } else {
                return sizeof(T) < sizeof(T2);
            }
        }
};
```

is it possible? The operator doesn't really need to be friend if we can use boost operators in some way to use it to generate the rest of operators.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably just use an overloaded function template:

```
template <typename T>
bool operator<(Foo<T> const& f1, Foo<T> const& f2) {
    return f1.bar < f2.bar;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
bool operator<(Foo<T1> const& f1, Foo<T2> const& f2) {
    return sizeof(T1) < sizeof(T2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my main problem is with the `class Foo : boost::less_than_comparable<Foo<T>, Foo<T2> > {` line beacause T2 is not declared there.

Comment: @vintitres : Right, which isn't something that can be worked around cleanly. This answer shows the clean approach.